# Jquery and server form validation

Tags: jquery

I'd like to know what the best way to handle form validation is where it pertains to server side. I'm really new to JQ and have successfully implemented a JSON submit. Before I had this implemented, I was doing all of my validation on the server end and echoing any error back out to the user. Now I'm looking at the completed form and wondering if coding the server stuff is even necessary. I know that if the user turns off Javascript that I should still have something on the server side that will do the validation but I'd like to know what the best practice would be for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice would be to validate all user data server side regardless of client side validation as any one can bypass JavaScript either by disabling it or injecting code onto the page to disable your validation.

Comment: Thanks Nalum. That's what I thought.